# Pylint Module 'cv2' has no 'merge' member

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, opencv

Have VSCode on my computer, for my Python development and the exact same extensions are present, yet on my laptop, I receive the error message in the header.

On my computer, I did not have to set anything up for Pylint to work correctly. The package 'cv2' is installed correctly as when the commands 'dir(cv2) || help(cv2)' is executed, the expected result is returned.

Has anyone encountered this problem? I could revert to using Komodo however VSCode is an excellent text editor for Python.

Comment: This seems like a common problem with Pylint. It seems to have a lot of false positives.

Comment: Can the false positives be ignored upon compile or just essentially like a .gitignore *cv2 package

Comment: one option is to use the below two comment lines in your code # pylint: disable=E0602 
# pylint: disable=E0611

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with VSCode but instead a problem with Pylint. Try running the below command from the commandline

```
pylint <your-py-file>
```

The code should execute fine in VSCode irrespective of this warning/error.

Comment: Terminal Output - pylint : The term 'pylint' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. Pylint has already been installed as well.

Comment: Is it in powershell? Maybe the pylint is not in the system path.

Comment: pylint is not in the path recognized by powershell. You might have to add it to the system path